# Linux Distribution With good Multimedia/Programming support To Be Installed On a 7.5GB USB Stick

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I can only afford a 7.5GB USB stick at the moment and with no internet connection.

I'm looking for a suitable Linux distribution with good multimedia support (codecs for audio/video content) and also good programming support which includes GCC/G++, VIM editor supporting syntax highlight and auto-indent. I intend to install a full fledged Linux operating system on a 7.5 GB USB stick and boot from it when I need it or may be even install it on a moderately powerful laptop.

Comment: "No Internet connection" is going to make this a bit more tricky/obscure...

Comment: That's ok. I'am aware that linux can be installed without an internet connection and can be updated later.

Comment: The problem is not the installation, it's the updating later.

Comment: [Sushi Huh Grabs Linux Packages for Offline Installation](http://lifehacker.com/5439607/sushi-huh-grabs-linux-packages-for-offline-installation)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Linux Mint. I am assuming that you can install it using UNetbootin, I have done so in the past and it contains all the things you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you install Knoppix 8.2 (or newer version, if there is a newer version when you read this). When you clone it from the iso file, it will automatically use the rest of the USB stick as storage for persistence so that you can install some extra program packages.

See the following links,

[www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html)

[www.knopper.net/knoppix-mirrors/index-en.html](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix-mirrors/index-en.html)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/install-to-debian#Knoppix](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/install-to-debian#Knoppix)